# Using symbols to represent counts in a for loop

Tags: python, loops, numpy

I have a CSV file that I've made a NumPy array from, I'm trying to iterate though the first column and produce a result of the counts in each row using the * symbol to represent the number.

```
trafficdata = np.loadtxt((input('vechicles: ')), delimiter=" ")    
a=trafficdata[:,1]    
print("Car Count")    
for i, b in enumerate(a,+1):    
     print(i, b)
```

It gives the result, but I want to change the 4.0 to ****. I know I need a line in the for loop but I can't figure out what I need.

```
1 4.0    
2 5.0    
3 4.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want as `b` times the `"*"` symbol? You can simply write:

```
print("%d %s" % (i, int(b) * "*"))
```

Comment: Thanks that works great, I knew it was simple I'm still trying to get to grips with it.

Comment: Could you accept my answer if you found it useful? :)

Answer (score 0):

as I understand it, you want to represent a number b by a sequence of b "*". If so, you can simply add this in the for loop:

```
result = int(b)*"*"
```

result is the string you need.